# How to execute Maven-Plugin multiple times

Tags: maven, reverse-engineering

I have two databases i'd like to generate hbm2java to.

```
<project>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version> 2.2</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>db1</id>
          <configuration>
          <components>
            <component>
              <name>hbm2java</name>
              ...
            </component>
          </components>
          <componentProperties>
            ...
            <configurationfile>.../hibernate1.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
          </componentProperties>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>db2</id>
          <configuration>
          <components>
            <component>
              <name>hbm2java</name>
              ...
            </component>
          </components>
          <componentProperties>
            ...
            <configurationfile>.../hibernate2.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
          </componentProperties>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      ...
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
  ...
</project>
```

Ok, if i run `mvn hibernate3:hbm2java` then it executes no execution!

This is the Log:

```
[INFO] >>> hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2java (default-cli) @ XXXXXXXXXXXXX >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ XXXXXXXXXXXXX ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2java (default-cli) @ XXXXXXXXXXXXX <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2java (default-cli) @ XXXXXXXXXXXXX ---
[INFO] using configuration task.
11:07:29,370  INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.3.1.GA
11:07:29,376  INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
11:07:29,381  INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
11:07:29,387  INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
[INFO] No hibernate configuration file loaded.
[INFO] No hibernate properties file loaded.
11:07:29,464  INFO org.hibernate.tool.Version - Hibernate Tools 3.2.4.GA
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i cant seperate the execution of hbm2java via the lifecycle.

I have a solution using a custom profile "generate":

```
<project>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>generate</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>db1</id>
                <configuration>
                <components>
                  <component>
                    <name>hbm2java</name>
                    ...
                  </component>
                </components>
                <componentProperties>
                  ...
                  <configurationfile>.../hibernate1.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
                </componentProperties>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>db2</id>
                <configuration>
                <components>
                  <component>
                    <name>hbm2java</name>
                    ...
                  </component>
                </components>
                <componentProperties>
                  ...
                  <configurationfile>.../hibernate2.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
                </componentProperties>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            ...
          </plugin>
          ...
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  ...
</project>
```

Now i need to execute 3 different executions:

1. `mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true` compile the reverse-engineer-strategy
2. `mvn compile -P generate` generate the classes
3. `mvn test` test the unit-tests

Answer (score 1):

The exeuctions only works in relationship with the life cycle which means you have to call:

```
mvn process-resources
```

instead of simply calling the goal of the plugin. Or a later phase like:

```
mvn compile
```

Comment: An additional question: i dont like the classes to be generated via compile. I like the classes be generated only via hibernate3:hbm2java.

Comment: The classes will generated during the generate-resources, cause the plugin is bound to that life cycle phase. Furthermore if you do a **mvn clean** every generated class will be removed so the best to stick with the maven life cycle and let the hibernate plugin generate the classes during the life-cycle. Generating via goal call you like to do in that way is not possible. It sound a little bit like you didn't understand the life-cycle. What's the reason not letting generation during the life cycle?

Comment: I specify a reversestrategy for the generation. This strategy must be compiled first! If i do a **maven clean** the reversestrategy is not available anymore and the **build fails**!

Comment: It would be help-full to see the full pom cause it sounds you have basic problem with your build. The usage of all generators in Maven is to generate during the generate-resources/generate-sources life cycle and let the compiler plugin compile the generated sources.

Comment: You already have all needed informations. The databases aren't always accessible and the sources are checked-in into a subversion, so the hbm2java is **operational** only if the db is available. There are too many facts and the problem is to specific.

Comment: The conclusion is: You can't go the way you like to go. That's it. If the generated sources are checked in it does not make sense. Than you should make a separate project which just contains the generation part and which uses the life cycle. The other projects can simply use the generated parts as dependencies.

Comment: Hey ein seperates Projekt bedingt durch eine Separate pom kann ich nicht rechtfertigen. Gibts nicht was mit Profilen?